# Owin Stage Markers

Tags: c#, owin, pipeline

Given this in my app startup ...

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
   return next.Invoke();
}).UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostAuthenticate);


app.Use((context, next) =>
{
   return next.Invoke();
}).UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

... why does the PostAuthenticate code execute before the Authenticate code?

I don't mean "why does the first app.use get called before the second app.use" I mean: Why does the first invoke get called before the second given that that the second should be happening earlier in the request pipeline?

**EDIT**

Related to this problem: [How am I getting a windows identity in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169759/how-am-i-getting-a-windows-identity-in-this-code)

Comment: The infrastructure will build the pipeline of middleware components based on the order in which they were added to the IAppBuilder object in the Configuration method.

Comment: so the stage markers serve no purpose ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's by design, according to the documentation: https://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline.

In the section *Stage Marker Rules*, you could read the following:

> The OWIN pipeline and the IIS pipeline is ordered, therefore calls to `app.UseStageMarker` must be in order. You cannot set the event handler to an event that precedes the last event registered with to `app.UseStageMarker`. For example, *after* calling:
>
> ```
> app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authorize);
> ```
>
> calls to `app.UseStageMarker` passing `Authenticate` or `PostAuthenticate` will not be honored, and no exception will be thrown. Owin middleware components (OMCs) run at the latest stage, which  by default is `PreHandlerExecute`. The stage markers are used to make them to run earlier. If you specify stage markers out of order, we round to the earlier marker. In other words, adding a stage marker says "Run no later than stage X". OMC's run at the earliest stage marker added after them in the OWIN pipeline.

Comment: Interesting, I had not seen this before. that explains the odd behaviour i've been seeing.
What a weird design.

Comment: `UseStageMarker` is an extension, so it requires `using Microsoft.Owin.Extensions;`

Comment: The statement of [earlier pipeline stages] "will not be honored" might be a typo in MS' documentation.  If UseStageMarker(Authorize) is called before UseStageMarker(Authenticate), everything is effectively run at the Authenticate stage since everything is 'rounded to the earlier marker'.  Similar to asker's observation and contrary to the documentation, the "Authorize" stage marker is not honored, not the other way around.  Fixing MS' typo might be to say "will **cause Authorize marker** to not be honored" instead of just "will not be honored".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even contrary to the documentation events in IIS are hooked up and processed in the order they are configured rather than in the order they should appear in the request lifecycle.

This feels like a bug in the owin request lifecycle to me but hey, I got my problem solved.